# CORS in Maplibre

Tags: openlayers, cors, maplibre-gl

The problem is reproduced in URL below:
https://jsfiddle.net/kochizufan/e8jgbu9q/

```
const libre = new maplibregl.Map({
  container: 'libre',
  style: {
    version: 8,
    sources: {
      s_contour7: {
        type: 'raster',
        tiles: [
          'https://grt.code4history.dev/cont7/18/1/{z}/{x}/{y}',
        ],
        tileSize: 256,
        attribution: 'MapLibre',
      },
    },
    layers: [
      {
        id: 'contour7',
        type: 'raster',
        source: 's_contour7',
        minzoom: 8,
        maxzoom: 14,
      },
    ],
  },
  center: [139.506540, 36.195698], // starting position [lng, lat]
  zoom: 13 // starting zoom
});
  
const ol6 = new ol.Map({
  target: 'ol',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        attributions: "OpenLayers",
      url: 'https://grt.code4history.dev/cont7/18/1/{z}/{x}/{y}',
      projection: "EPSG:3857",
      tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
        minZoom: 8,
        maxZoom: 14,
        tileSize: 256,
      }),
    })
  })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([139.506540, 36.195698]),
    zoom: 13
  })
});
```

Raster tile map source called from MapLibre causes CORS error.
But, exactly same setting tiles can be read from OpenLayers 6.5.
What is the difference between calling from OpenLayers6 and that of MapLibre?
Are there any option switch for solving CORS error in MapLibre?

Comment: MapLibre uses WebGL and must have CORS access to images.  You would have the same problem with OpenLayers if using `ol.layer.WebGLTile`,

Comment: OK, then this should be the problem of server side, right?

Comment: Yes, either configure the server or, if you are using a 3rd party source you do not control you will need a proxy.

Comment: Thank you very much! I misunderstood that there are no difference between calling images from canvas and from WebGL.